# Angular, jsrsasign & random options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cryptography, cryptojs

I'm using jsrsasign [Keyutil](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/blob/master/keyutil-1.0.js) to generate a keypair in an Angular App.  It leverages the jsbn [rng](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/rng.js) for randomness.  Essentially, I am angularizing the [CSTRtool](http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/tool_csr.html) and wish to add a couple of extra options.

I'd like to provide use of the [ANUs quantum random number generator](https://qrng.anu.edu.au/API/api-demo.php) and possibly window.crypto at a future point in time. If I'm really honest, all the solutions I've come up with so far have been pretty crude and involve hacking the rng.js file (example below) & don't use any angular goodness such as $http for retrieving random values, so I'm throwing it out there to get some ideas.

```
function rng_get_bytes(ba) {
  var url = "https://qrng.anu.edu.au/API/jsonI.php?type=uint8&length=" + ba.length;
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false ); // false for synchronous request
  xmlHttp.send( null );
  var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
  ba = jsonResponse.data;
}

function SecureRandom() {}

SecureRandom.prototype.nextBytes = rng_get_bytes;
```

Comment: I've found some pointers for window.crypto using forge https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/284 . Forge might be the way forward for me!

Comment: Your "question" is quite confusing. Can you clarify what you currently have and what you want to have?